# Sharepoint--Increment the metadata when document is copy or added, but dont increment when move

Tags: sharepoint

I have an event handler and Itemadded event.
I want to increment the metadata only if document is added or copy from one libraray to another, not if it is moved.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to provide your end user an easy way to move the document.  That can easily be done with the Move() method of the SPFile object.  Once in the code for the move, you can manually increment the metadata field.

Start here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms470176.aspx